# On change of dropdown value, the <div>'s should be updated with appropriate data

Tags: jquery, html

I need to have something like this. on change of dropdown lists , the two 's should be updated with the appropriate data. 
 for e.g. if somebody selects John Smith , then in those 's his Name & mobile number should be updated.

**HTML code:**

```
<select id="users" name="select2" class="input-txt-smp pad2" style="width:120px;">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option  mobilenumber="1234567890" value="John Smith">John Smith</option>
    <option  mobilenumber="7894561230"  value="Raymond Roasrio">Raymond Roasrio</option>
</select>

<div id="usrname" class="fontblk20">  </div>
<div id="usrnum" class="fontblk14 margtop10 leftFloat margleft7"> </div>
```

**jQuery code**

```
$("#users").change(function()
{
    $('.scrsngl-outbor').show()
         var selected = $(this).find(':selected');

         $("#usrname").text(selected.val());
         $("#usrnum").text(selected.attr('mobilenumber'));
}
```

It is workable from the above codes. Even if you select second option, the 's are updated with the appropriate data.

**My questions here are,**

1) is this the right way to achieve this tasks. I feel no, because its not just the question of two `<div>`'s of (name & number) there might be many more fields to be updated.
e.g, email id, birth date etc etc...

2) I am ok with json , but how to incorporate

3) I dont want if else statement's either like `(if(usrname == John Smith ......) )` becuase it will be going to `dynamic dropdown users` will be updated, hence no hard code please.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Apply a data attribute to the option with the id of the div to update the value with then you can have some jquery similar to the following:

```
<option data-update="phone-number-div" value="1234">Phone Number</option>

$("#" + selected.data("update")).text(selected.attr("value"));

<div id="phone-number-div">Update me</div>
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to say, you can use data attributes for multiple values as well e.g. name, phone number, age etc.

Comment: Hi listylister, you have hard coded the value="1234". I dont want it in attributes of <option>. let the data come in json..

Comment: okay...not sure why you want it in Json - is it coming from a server side application? If so that's fine just do an ajax call to the server side method using jquery and then call the above jquery code in the success method of the ajax call passing in the json value instead of the attribute.